# How to do error handling in Android Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

how are you?

I made the implementation of Room based on jetpack`s page, worked fine in my tests, but when adding with the sync occurred the following error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY[787])
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:995)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeInsert(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:51)
        at androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insert(EntityInsertionAdapter.java:64)
        at br.com.sat.cronos.database.dao.tarefa.TarefaDAO_Impl.inserir(TarefaDAO_Impl.java:142)
        at br.com.sat.cronos.database.dao.tarefa.TarefaDAO_Impl.inserir(TarefaDAO_Impl.java:17)
        at br.com.sat.cronos.repository.tarefa.TarefaRepository$salvar$1.invoke(TarefaRepository.kt:37)
        at br.com.sat.cronos.repository.tarefa.TarefaRepository$salvar$1.invoke(TarefaRepository.kt:11)
        at br.com.sat.cronos.asynctask.BaseAsyncTask.doInBackground(BaseAsyncTask.kt:12)
        at br.com.sat.cronos.asynctask.BaseAsyncTask.doInBackground(BaseAsyncTask.kt:7)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
```

I ended up creating a BaseDao class to use as generic so i can use it dynamically:

```
package br.com.sat.cronos.database.dao

import androidx.annotation.WorkerThread
import androidx.room.*


@Dao
interface BaseDAO<T> {

    /**
     * Insere um objeto no banco de dados
     *
     * @param obj
     */
    @Insert
    fun inserir(obj: T)

    /**
     * Insere um array de objetos no banco de dados
     *
     * @param list
     */
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    @WorkerThread
    fun inserir(list: List<T>)

    /**
     * Atualizar um objeto no banco de dados
     *
     * @param obj
     */
    @Update
    fun atualizar(obj: T)

    /**
     * Remove um objeto do banco de dados
     *
     * @param obj
     */
    @Delete
    fun remover(obj: T)

}
```

And I make the call as follows when inserting:

```
 fun salvar(ta: Tarefa, callback: (Unit?) -> Unit) {
        try {
            BaseAsyncTask(executar = {
                if (buscaPorId(ta.id) == null) {
                    dao?.inserir(ta)
                } else {
                    dao?.atualizar(ta)
                }
            }, finaliza = callback)
                .execute()
        } catch (erro: Exception) {
            CrashlyticsUtil.enviaErro(context, TAG, erro)
        }
    }
```

So i wonder how i could handle the error. Right now the application crashs while someone uses it. I want to not crash it at all and send the error to my custom CrashlyticsUtil class.

**UPDATE**

Class Tarefa

```
package br.com.sat.cronos.model.tarefa

import androidx.room.*
import br.com.sat.cronos.holder.api.tarefa.TarefaApiHolder
import br.com.sat.cronos.model.equipamento.CategoriaEquipamento
import java.io.Serializable

@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = CategoriaEquipamento::class,
            parentColumns = ["ID"],
            childColumns = ["ID_CAT_EQUIPAMENTO"]
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = AgrupadorTarefa::class,
            parentColumns = ["ID"],
            childColumns = ["ID_AGRUP_TAREFA"]
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Sistema::class,
            parentColumns = ["ID"],
            childColumns = ["ID_SISTEMA"]
        )
    ]
)
open class Tarefa : Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ID")
    var id: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "ID_CAT_EQUIPAMENTO")
    var idCategoriaEquipamento: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "ID_AGRUP_TAREFA")
    var idAgrupadorTarefa: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "ID_SISTEMA")
    var idSistema: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "DESCRICAO")
    var descricao: String = ""

    @ColumnInfo(name = "SELECIONADO")
    var selecionado: Boolean = false

    @ColumnInfo(name = "ATENDIMENTO")
    var atendimento: Boolean = false

    @ColumnInfo(name = "ATIVO")
    var ativo: Boolean = true

    constructor()

    constructor(ta: TarefaApiHolder) {
        this.id = ta.id!!
        this.idSistema = ta.idSistema!!
        this.idCategoriaEquipamento = ta.idCategoriaEquipamento!!
        this.idAgrupadorTarefa = ta.idAgrupadorTarefa!!
        this.descricao = ta.descricao!!
        this.selecionado = ta.selecionado!!
        this.atendimento = ta.atendimento!!
        this.ativo = ta.ativo!!
    }

    @Ignore
    constructor(
        id: Long,
        idSistema: Long,
        idCategoriaEquipamento: Long,
        idAgrupadorTarefa: Long,
        descricao: String,
        selecionado: Boolean,
        atendimento: Boolean,
        ativo: Boolean
    ) {
        this.id = id
        this.idSistema = idSistema
        this.idCategoriaEquipamento = idCategoriaEquipamento
        this.idAgrupadorTarefa = idAgrupadorTarefa
        this.descricao = descricao
        this.selecionado = selecionado
        this.atendimento = atendimento
        this.ativo = ativo
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return descricao
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/agrosner/DBFlow/issues/636#issuecomment-184776394).

BTW, Please share `Tarefa` class code.

Comment: @MirMiladHosseiny Just update the question with Tarefa class code

Comment: When you call `salvar` method, what are the values of `idCategoriaEquipamento`, `idAgrupadorTarefa` & `idSistema` fields?

Comment: @MirMiladHosseiny Right now the fields are null. To understand better, this is a syncronization routine. Sometimes the required fields like `idAgrupadorTarefa` and `idSistema` based in their own model are not synced yet.

Comment: This error happens when you forget to add entities from foreign keys first. Because your database doesn’t have entities  CategoriaEquipamento, AgrupadorTarefia and Sistema which ids you using in your Tarefia entities

Comment: @IliaKuzmin Thanks for the explanation, but I want to know how I handle the issue.

Comment: You should define foreign keys nullable.

Comment: @MirMiladHosseiny Yes, it is correct, this is to occur. I want to validate this error so that the application doesn't crash